# Does the Brazil Air Pass still exist?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, brazil, south-america

In many forums and blogs about air travel in Brazil the "Brazil Air Pass" (or sometimes a "South American Airpass") is mentioned. With this airpass, you can take multiple flights with the same airline inside Brazil, usually for a cheaper prize than when booking the flights individually.

However, I am not able to find this airpass on the websites of the airlines mentioned in the blogs. Do these airpasses still exist, or where they abolished?

Edit based on comment: The only thing I am able to do on some websites is fill in a form to "get contacted with more details". When buying plane tickets (or anything else on the internet) I never had to do something like this. Normally, I enter my information and press "buy" at the end to buy it directly. Is this normal for the Brazil Air Pass that you have to do it with these kind of forms where you cannot buy it but only indicate your interest?

Comment: A Google search immediately revealed multiple commercial websites selling the Brazil/SA Air Pass, and disclosing booking rules and limitations. Some of the sites — I have no affiliation — look like serious, long-term players in the travel market. What do you want to know?

Comment: When I use Google and check the first 25 results I find the following: 13 blogs/forums talking about the airpass and linking to some of the other websites, 7 websites where you can fill in a form to "receive more information" but are not able to buy the airpass, 3 websites of airlines to book individual flights, 2 websites of airlines resulting in an error 404. The later Google results seem to be similar. Are you getting different results?

Comment: Did you "fill in a form" to see what happes? Did you contact one of the looks-legit sources (e.g., https://www.brol.com/airpass/) with other contact methods to ask them?

Comment: 6 Years ago it did... it was a long process over the phone to have it done but in the end it was possible to reach the same price via an OTA purchasing each leg. The main rule was that the pass could only be bought from outside the country... now a lot happened in 6 years, so I have no idea if it is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

The major airlines in Brazil are LATAM, Azul and Gol. I've found press releases from [the](https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENET/frmDownloadDocumento.aspx?Tela=ext&numProtocolo=187928&descTipo=IPE&CodigoInstituicao=1) [three](https://www.panrotas.com.br/noticia-turismo/aviacao/2015/08/azul-lanca-brazil-air-pass-para-americanos_118006.html) [companies](https://www.publituris.pt/2016/01/27/gol-lanca-airpass-brasil-e-airpass-america-do-sul) announcing a Brazil Air Pass for foreigners in the past (before 2016). None of the companies advertise those passes anymore. [Azul](https://www.voeazul.com.br/en/airpass) used to have a [promotional page](https://www.voeazul.com.br/en/airpass) for its Pass, but the page is now down.

There is some more recent information regarding a [South America Pass](https://www.latamtrade.com/content/dam/latam-portal-agencias/australia/Brochure_airpass_ingles%202018.pdf) from LATAM. The language is geared towards travel agencies, so I'm not sure if they're really available to the general public.

Given the uncertainty around the passes, I would be wary of any Brazil Air Pass offer I'd encounter on the internet. I advise you to contact the mentioned companies.

Answer (score 3):

Since there seems to be no way of buying an airpass directly, I did fill in a form on brol.com/airpass and asked about the airpasses of Gol and Azul and about some further details not specified on the website.

I recieved the following autoreply:

> IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT BRAZIL AIRPASS AND COVID
>
> Because of severe disruption in Airline's flight networks and
> decreased seat availability for the Brazil Airpass Product, it is
> unlikely that seats are available for this product.
>
> Therefore, alternatively our agents will check the best available
> options for your trip, other than the Brazil Airpass.
>
> We hope that in the future, the Airlines will make more seats
> available for the Brazil Airpass, and we can sell the product again.

The next day, I recieved an answer with a price offer for Gol and with a request for my name, credit card authorization form etc. to book the tickets. I recieved no details for Azul and concerning my additional questions. Since the price offered for Gol was not attractive enough compared to booking individual flights, I did not take the offer. Therefore, I cannot tell what would have happend next.

Edit based on comment: The price offered by brol was around 800 US$, compared to 1'000 US$ for booking individual flights. However, it was not clear from the offer, whether the 800 US$ included the fee for the luggage (23 kg) or whether there would be something on top. So, the "airpass" was around 20% cheaper at most (due to the luggage maybe even less). For me, the significant loss of flexibility (only being able to fly with the airline Gol and not with Latam and Azul) was not worth the 20%.

Comment: *an answer with a price offer for Gol* => what was the price offered?

Comment: Although they say the lack of Brazil Air Passes are due to COVID-19, in reality these passes seem to be removed from the market way before the pandemic. For example, the last live version of the [Azul promo page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160629172308/http://www.voeazul.com.br:80/en/airpass) mentioned in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180220/126522) is from July 2016. I think the Brazil Airpass thing is more of a marketing gimmick from Brol.com than anything else.